# Assertion in python using the last 20 of the Iris dataset

Tags: python, assert, assertion

I am trying to write an assert statement to prove that the last 20 rows of the Virginica subset of the iris dataset I pulled is indeed equal to 'Virginica'

So far what I tried:

```
assert (last_20['variety']) == 'Virginica')
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-9498f7345325> in <module>
      8 # test that the subset has the class Virginica
      9
---> 10 assert ((last_20['variety']) == 'Virginica')
     11 
     12 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1439     @final
   1440     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1441         raise ValueError(
   1442             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1443             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried removing the parenthesis like it suggested before, but i still get an error.

Comment: Is `last_20['variety']` a series?  Then, as the error message suggests, use `assert (last_20['variety']== "Virginica").all()` to check that all values of the series are equal to that string constant, or `(last_20['variety'] == "Virginica").any()` to check that at least one value is that string.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that earlier, but I put it in the wrong spot. it worked. thank you so much. HAve a great day